# Is QCompleter broken on Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm trying to build an app for both android and desktop with qt 5.13 and facing some problems with QCompleter and QLineEdit on android
the completer doesn't popup on android and when I finish insert a word that is in the list of the completer the completer doubles the content of QLineEdit and I can't clear the QLineEdit or do anything with it again , every time I touch it the contents is copied and pasted

Operation Systems I tested on :

Windows 10 x64 v1903

Android 8.1 Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus

this is the code I'm using QCompleter in :

in header file :

```
namespace Ui {
class DictionaryGui;
}

class DictionaryGui : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DictionaryGui(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~DictionaryGui();

private slots:
    void on_SearchBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::DictionaryGui *ui;
    QStringListModel mdl;
    QCompleter completer;
};
```

in cpp file

```
DictionaryGui::DictionaryGui(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DictionaryGui),
    completer(&mdl)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QScroller::grabGesture(ui->ResultsList);
    ui->DictionaryWidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget#DictionaryWidget {background-color: rgb(144, 202, 249);}");
    QString input_style = R"##(QLineEdit {border: 1px solid #ccc;
                         border-radius: 10px; }
                            QLineEdit:focus {
                               border: 3px solid #55aaff;
                          }
                          )##";
    ui->InputText->setStyleSheet(input_style);

    int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/icons/gulf-semibold.ttf");
    if (id != -1)
    {
        QString font_family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
        QFont font(font_family, 14);
        qDebug() << "[*] loaded the font : " << font_family;
        ui->InputText->setFont(font);
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "[!] failed to load the font !\n";
    }

    QStringList list({"word", "man", "human", "test", "world", "wonder", "what",
                      u8"كلمة", u8"كلام" , u8"كلهم", u8"كلا", u8"كلاهما"});
    mdl.setStringList(list);
    completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    completer.setFilterMode(Qt::MatchStartsWith);
    ui->InputText->setCompleter(&completer);

}
```

on windows this works well :

[image: qcompleter windows]

but on android this the completer is broken

Edit : I tested on a phone with Android 5 and the above code works but still doesn't work on android 8.1

Comment: If this *does* turn out to be a Qt bug, do remember to report it 

Comment: I asked on qt forum if this is already known to happen or I'm doing something wrong and still no response

Comment: I tested on Android 5 and it's working so the bug for now is on Android 8.1